# Не подключается к ESP32 по bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, esp32, bluetooth-le

У меня не получается подключится к новой плате ESP32 с помощью bluetooth (LE). Использовал стандартную библиотеку ESP32: BluetoothSerial, пример SerialToBluetoothSerial, пин не включал. Для подключения использовал мамин телефон (A51), использовал приложения Bluetooth terminal, nRF connect и BLE scanner. Все приложения (в том числе настройки Blutooth) видят ESP32, но не подключаются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144794/discussion-on-question-by-ilya-dudelzak----esp32--bluetooth); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144794/discussion-on-question-by-ilya-dudelzak----esp32--bluetooth Все комментарии теперь здесь